# How to use subpackage of nested Cargo.toml git project?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

I want to use the package [`substrate-test-runtime-client`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/test-utils/runtime/client/Cargo.toml) from the [substrate GitHub repo](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git).

```ini
[dependency]
substrate-test-runtime-client = [git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "master"]
```

Above Cargo.toml syntax doesn't resolve the issue. How can I extract, compile, and use a subpackage of umbrella package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to use curly brackets to specify an inline TOML table.

So either add the following to your `Cargo.toml` file.

```ini
[dependencies]
substrate-test-runtime-client = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "master" }
```

Or use this which is equivalent

```ini
[dependencies.substrate-test-runtime-client]
git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git"
branch = "master"
```

Cargo will crawl the downloaded repository looking for a package called `substrate-test-runtime-client`. See [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1462).